# check current category of layered navigation in magento

Tags: magento, navigation, categories, layer

get current category in layer navigation,im using this code but it is not working please help

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output') ?>
          <?php $_category = $this->getCurrentCategory(); >
```

Answer (score 0):

please use the below code

```
if(Mage::registry('current_category'))
    {
    $cat=Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
    /* used for category level*/
    }
    else{
    $cat=2; // 2 is root category id
    /* used for serch level*/
    }
```

hope it will be working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Current Category id on navigation, you can do like this.

```
 <?php $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();?>
```

Hopes this will solve your problem.